# jQuery escape apostrophe in option value

Tags: jquery

I want to select the option with a particular value. And the value of the element contains apostrophe in it. In this case it does not select the element properly.

```
var selectedValue= "Test'1";
jQuery("option[value='" + selectedValue + "']"); // does not find option with value as "Test'1"
```

Sample Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JSWorld/26JTy/4/

Here it does not alert, when I select an option that has an apostrophe in it.

Answer (score 7):

Escape using double back-slashes:

```
var selectedValue = jQuery(this).val().replace("'", "\\'").replace('"', '\\"');
```

Your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/26JTy/6/

Answer (score 1):

This would give you the same problem if you have any values with double quotes ("), but you could flip the single and double quotes in your code:

```
var selectedValue= "Test'1";
jQuery('option[value="' + selectedValue + '"]');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/26JTy/5/

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me in my case:

```
var selectedValue = jQuery(this).val().replace("'", "&#39;");
```